# Smallest angle between vector and x-axis

Tags: vectors

Working in 3d space, I'm given the vector $A=(1,2,3)$ and I'm supposed to find the smallest angle $\theta$ between $A$ and the x-axis.

Does it have to do with setting the x-axis as a vector, i.e: $R$ and 
calculating $cos\theta=(A*R)/(|A||R|)$ ?

I'm not really sure where to even begin.

edit:
This is my guess:
$A=(1,2,3)$ and x-axis$=R=(1,0,0)$ so that $|A|=\sqrt{(1^2+2^2+3^2)}=\sqrt{14}$

and $A*R=1*1+2*0+3*0=1$

so that $cos\theta=1/\sqrt{14}$  giving an angle of $\theta=74.5^o$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Your approach is the correct one.

Comment: If so, does it mean that the vector $R=(1,0,0)$ ?

Comment: Yes. That's - one possibile choice for -  the vector. 
PS: don't forget that two vectors enclose two complementary angles!

Comment: I'm lost again. Complementary angles? Is this something I need to take in account when doing the calculation?